# Xcode 7.3.1 crash on splash screen: Library not loaded

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

Yesterday I updated to Xcode 7.3.1 through the AppStore and since then the project does not compile.
To make sure I created a brand new project, added a single, simple, pod, and tried to run - same error.
This is my `Podfile` on the new project:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'test' do
    pod 'SwiftDate', '~> 2.0'
end
```

The only things I changed other than a brand new project are these lines in `ViewControlle.swift`:

```
import SwiftDate

//then inside viewDidLoad():
let d = 1.days
print(d)
```

Every time I run (it builds successfully) the app breaks on the splash screen with the following error:
(tried with another pod - Alamofire - exactly same error)

[image: Xcode Screenshot of given error]

I tried solutions mentioned on SO for the given error (make the pods framework as Optional and disable bit code).

**EDIT:** Even weirder - I created a BRAND NEW PROJECT, no cocoapods at all, ran, and got the same error for `libswiftCore`:

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F23F9B74-27BC-41F0-BF29-B5DF3CC6FF7F/test2.app/test2
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F23F9B74-27BC-41F0-BF29-B5DF3CC6FF7F/test2.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F23F9B74-27BC-41F0-BF29-B5DF3CC6FF7F/test2.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
```

So I guess it's not even a cocoapods but an Xcode issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Several things behind the scenes are likely at play here, but when I've had this issue the solution has been one of two things:

- If any embedded binaries (such as frameworks) contain Swift code, then in your project build settings you should set "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" to YES. Then clean the project and try again.
- Sometimes, even when I have the setting above set to YES, I still get the error. Simply cleaning the project has always been the solution for me. (Menu Bar: Product > Clean)

Whether this helps or not, it's probably worth submitting a bug report to Apple.